# Facebook Thumbnail Opacity

Tags: facebook, opacity

I created an image with Inkscape. The background image has opacity set at 30%. I want to use it in Facebook to get clicks for our website (citizens group).  I uploaded the image (.PNG or .JPG) to our website media library. On our website, I set the Facebook Thumbnail to be the image. The image looks great on Facebook, **until I boost the post (i.e. Facebook Ad).  When I boost the post, the background opacity goes to 100% and you can't read the text that's over the background image?!?**  Weird, 'eh???  I'm no graphics expert. I googled to no avail. I'm pretty good with HTML and know what CSS is, but I don't know how to add that stuff to an image.  I read about Open Graph tags, but...please help me! :-(

Comment: Thanks for the down vote.  If it's a stupid question, give me a link to some relevant educational document or article.

Comment: I don’t think it makes much sense to use images with opacity in an environment you don’t control to begin with. Plus, JPEG doesn’t even support it, so I am not too sure what effect you expect from that, if you upload it as such. Can really only recommend that you try with “solid” images in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that JPEG doesn't support transparency was everything I needed. Apparently, my initial test of JPEG was faulty, because it worked the second time I tried it...thanks!